# change limit max output file vscode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, visual-studio-code

when working on Jupyter notebook in vscode, when the output is too big, there is this. [image]

The thing is when looking at the output data in the text editor, I can only see the first 1000. any idea how to change that?

Comment: Are you sure that you are only seeing 1000 lines? I just did a quick check printing 50000 lines in a python notebook in a loop and opening up in the text editor showed all 50000 lines.

Answer (score -1):

Settings

[image: 1]

So you can simply open settings and change the output size. Don't forget to restart the vscode if it does not work.(Click on the settings to see the image)

Comment: This changes the number of lines on notebook, not on the output file.